# Como gerar Fuzzy Attribute do Factory Boy antes da execução de cada teste?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, testes-de-unidade

Estou criando testes unitários para performar testes de integração da minha aplicação web. As ferramentas que estou utilizando são: **Mongomock** para criar uma instância temporária do banco para os testes e **Factory Boy** para criar instâncias mock das minhas entidades.

Em cada test_case, gero um objeto mock, salvo no banco e testo a rota correspondente. A seguir, faço os asserts necessários.

```
random_application = MockApplicationFactory.build()
random_application.save()
```

Através do **Test.App** e do **Paste.deploy** estabeleci um ambiente particular para executar os testes.

```
def setUp(self):
        '''
        This method is called before each test's execution and it set's up the environment for tests execution. It
         creates, among other things:
        - Mongomock connect through mongoengine in the test execution context;
        - Loads WSGI using a combination of the libraries webtest and paste.deploy;
        - Creates mocked function calls that are necessary to perform the tests.
        :return:
        '''
        # changes db connection to mongo mock
        # builds the test app to respond to requests
        # mock authentication

    def tearDown(self):
        '''
        Method called after the execution of each test. This is used to ensure that both the Database current connection
        and the Mocked methods are proplerly reseted in between the tests.
        :return:
        '''
```

Contudo, minha entidade Application foi definida com o campo "name" determinado como "required" e "unique".

```
class Application(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True, unique = True)
```

Para contornar essa restrição, decidi usar o decorator `@factory.post_generation` do **Factory Boy** visando criar um novo "name" antes da execução de cada teste.

```
class MockApplicationFactory(factory.Factory):
    """
    Factory class for mock applications
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Application

    credentials = ['test']

    @factory.post_generation
    def random_name(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        name = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyText(length=10).fuzz()
```

Mesmo assim, após rodar os test_cases com **Pytest**, continuo recebendo a mensagem de erro "Tried to save duplicate unique keys". Esse erro vai de encontro às definições citadas acima, referentes ao **Mongoengine**.

Gostaria de saber **como posso gerar um "name" aleatório para cada objeto mock de forma que esse seja atualizado antes da execução de cada teste.**

Eu poderia definir o campo "name" durante a criação de cada objeto mock nos test_cases, porém busco entender melhor funcionamento do Factory Boy e das outras ferramentas citadas.

- Observação_0: os test_cases fazem parte do module "test" e os objetos
  mock são criados no module "object_factories";
- Observação_1: os detalhes de configuração do ambiente foram emitidos,
  pois acredito que a solução do problema passa pelo Factory Boy.